# How to prove that $x = a^{-1} b$ is unique? ($a^{-1}$ is already proved unique.)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In the text I read, it proved that $a^{-1}$ unique. But then it goes by saying uniqueness of $x = a^{-1} b$ follows from the fact that $a^{-1}$ is unique.

---

Update: Here is the complete text (from p.20 of *Abstract Algebra* by Dummit and Foote)

[image]

Comment: For a given $b$ if $a^{-1}$ is unique shouldn't $x$ be unique by default?

Comment: @sai-kartik That's what I thought, but I'm looking for the derivation of its proof. Something like proving identity is unique.

Comment: Just added the intended text in question.

Comment: @AriRoyceHidayat I added an answer that explains almost surely what was intended (which is not what was in the answer you accepted  - which has now been changed).

Comment: For the record the above Proposition is from p.20 of *Abstract Algebra* by Dummit and Foote.

Answer (score 6):

The claim that  "the uniqueness of $x$ follows because $\,a^{-1}$ is unique" is incorrect and misleading. The proof uses only the *existence* of $\,a^{-1}$ to deduce the uniqueness of solutions of $\,ax = b.\,$ Let's examine the proof. If $\,a,b,x\in G\,$ a monoid, and $\,a\,$ has a $\rm\color{#c00}{left}$ inverse $\,a'\in G,\,$ i.e.  $\,\color{#c00}{a'a = 1}\,$ then

$$\qquad\begin{align}  b \,&=\, ax\\
\Rightarrow\  a'b \,&=\, a'(ax)\\
&=\, (\color{#c00}{a'a})x \ \ \ {\rm by\ multiplication\ is\ associative}\\
&=\,  \color{#c00}1x\\
&=\, x\end{align}$$

Thus every root $\,x\,$ of $\,ax=b\,$ is equal to $\,a'b,\,$ so roots are unique - at most one root exists (since if $\,r_2,r_1$ are roots then $\,r_2 = a'b = r_1\Rightarrow\, r_2 = r_1).\,$  The proof did not use *uniqueness* of the (left) inverse $\,a'.\,$ Rather it used only its *existence* (to cancel $\,a).\,$ Even if - hypothetically - there were multiple inverses the proof would still work fine because it only needs to choose one of them.

---

**Remark** $ $ The *existence* of a root follows if $\,a'\,$ is also a $\rm\color{#0a0}{right}$ inverse: $\,\color{#0a0}{aa'=1},\,$ since then the above arrow reverses by scaling by $\,a\,$ (or we can directly verify $\,x = a'b\,$ is a root: $\, ax = a(a'b) = (\color{#0a0}{aa'})b = b)$.

In the special case $\,b = 1\,$ the proof actually yields *uniqueness* of two-sided inverses, since it shows that if there exists a left inverse $\,a'$ of $\,a,\,$ i.e. $\,a'a = 1\,$ and there also exists a right inverse $\,x,\,$ i.e. $\,ax = 1,\,$ then $\,a' = x,\,$ i.e. left = right inverse, a result which is [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/15849/242). Thus - as above - if $\,a',a''$ are left inverses then $a'' = x = a'$ so $\,a'' = a'\,$ Similarly for uniqueness of right inverses.

More generally, to show that a set $S$ is a *singleton* it suffices to prove  $\,s\in S\iff s = a.\,$ Above is the special case when $\,S\,$ is a set of roots of an equation.

There is much further discussion of this subtlety in an old sci.math thread [linked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/15465/242) (in the more concrete case of the additive group of real numbers). As is clear from that thread, this point often proves puzzling to beginners even in very concrete groups.

Comment: I couldn't understand the proof, especially the part of how we could get $x' = ab^{-1}$.

Comment: May you please also show how we could get $x' = ab^{-1}$ from $ax' = b$?

Comment: @Ari I edited my answer to show explicitly that the uniqueness of $\,a^{-1}\,$ is never used.

Comment: The uniqueness in the text is necessary to ensure multiplication by $a^{-1}$ is unique (this is the uniqueness proof I asked) which has been answered well by Chris Custer’s previous answer. In your proof, you are using circular argument because $r’$ just refers back to $a^{-1} b$.

Comment: @Ari  Not true. I updated my answer to elaborate on such. Hopefully it is clearer now.