# what does $x|1$ mean in a UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, divisibility, unique-factorization-domains

so I'm working on a problem in a UFD and in some part of the problem I concluded that $x|1$? what does this tell us about $x$?
I was thinking well it means that for some $r$ we have $xr=1$ and that means $x$ is a unit now I have to get back to an equality: $d'=cdx$

I need to get rid of the x? how does $x|1$ help?.

Comment: $d' = cdx$ now implies that $d'r = cd$.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, $x\mid 1$ means that $xr=1$ for some $r$. Then $x$ is a unit and has a unique inverse $r=x^{-1}$. Then you have $d'x^{-1} = cd$.

Comment: Only the *existence* of an inverse is required, not *uniqueness.* This is an oft-misunderstood point. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3486032/242) for further discussion.

Comment: If its not unique I cannot write $x^{-1}$.

Comment: The proof needs only the *existence* of $\,r\,$ with $\,xr = 1,\,$ not  uniqueness. Even if hypothetically there were multiple such $r$ the proof would still work. See the linked thread for details.

Answer (score 0):

> For some $\,d\,$ we have $\,da=1,\,$ so $\,a\,$ is a unit. Now I need to get rid of $\,a\,$ in $\,ax = b$

Whenever $\,\color{#c00}{a\mid 1},\,$ scaling by $\,a^{-1}\,$ is a special case of *cancelling* $\,a,\,$ by   $\,c=1\,$ below.

**Lemma** $\ \ \,\color{#c00}{a\mid c},\ ax = b\!\:\color{#c00}c\ \,\Rightarrow\ x = b(c/a)\ $ **if** $\,a\,$ is cancellable.

**Proof** $\ \ \ \,\color{#c00}{da\! =\! c},\ ax = b\color{#c00}{da}\Rightarrow\, x = b\:\!d,\,$ by cancelling $\,a.\ \ \small\bf QED$

So the result is "obvious" once we understand how cancellation works. But inverses are so ubiquitous that it helpful to know this in both forms, i.e. scaling $\,ax = b\,$ by the inverse of $\,a,\,$ or cancelling $\,\color{#c00}a\,$ from its multiple $\color{#c00}1=a\:\!a^{-1}$ in $\,b = b\cdot\color{#c00}1$.