# Product of two negative numbers is positive

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the practical proof for $-1(-1)=+1$. Actually multiplication is repetitive addition. I am struggling how can I provide an activity to prove practically $-1(-1)=+1$

Comment: It's not a matter of proof -- but a _convention_ that happens to make the laws of arithmetic hold with greater generality than other possible conventions for the product of negative numbers would.

Comment: I'm not sure why people keep claiming that multiplication is repeated addiction. Or exponentiation is repeated multiplication. All of these operation are only defined that way on natural number, but there is no reasons to expect that they are still defined the same way once it is extended, nor even the same property. See also: exponentiation with exponent being matrices; fractional derivative.

Comment: Again, it is hard to find an "intuitive" insight. We can start with multiplication as repeted addition. Then, move on to multiplication of a negative number for a positive one: thus, $5 \times (-2)=-10$ becuse we add five time the quantity $-2$, and this is "obviously" a negative quantity (we move to the left with reference to $0$). Finally, we must think to mult for $-1$ as reversing the direction. Thus $(-5) \times (-2) = 10$ becuse it is : $(-1) \times 5 \times (-2) = (-1) \times (-10)$.

Answer (score 9):

**Law of Signs** proof: $\rm\,\ (-x)(-y) = (-x)(-y) + x(\overbrace{-y + y}^{\large =\,0}) = (\overbrace{-x+x}^{\large =\,0})(-y) + xy = xy$

Equivalently, evaluate $\rm\:\overline{(-x)(-y) +} \overline{ \underline {x(-y)}} \underline{ +\,xy}\, $ in 2 ways, noting each over/under term $ = 0$

Said more conceptually, $\rm\:(-x)(-y)\ $ and $\rm\:xy\:$ are both inverses of $\rm\ x(-y)\ $ so they are equal by **uniqueness of inverses**: if $\,a\,$ has two additive inverses $\,\color{#c00}{-a}\,$ and $\,\color{#0a0}{-a},\,$  then

$$\color{#c00}{-a}\, =\, \color{#c00}{-a}+\overbrace{(a+\color{#0a0}{-a})}^{\large =\,0}\, =\, \overbrace{(\color{#c00}{-a}+a)}^{\large =\,0}+\color{#0a0}{-a}\, =\, \color{#0a0}{-a} $$

This proof of the Law of Signs uses well-known laws of positive integers (esp. the *distributive law*), so if we require that these laws *persist* in the larger system of positive *and* negative integers, then the Law of Signs is a logical consequence of these basic laws of positive integers.

These fundamental laws of "numbers" are axiomatized by the algebraic structure known as a [ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29), and various specializations thereof. Since the above proof uses only *ring laws* (most notably the *distributive law*), the Law of Signs holds true in every ring, e.g. rings of polynomials, power series, matrices, differential operators, etc. In fact every nontrivial ring theorem (i.e. one that does not degenerate to a theorem about the underlying additive group or multiplicative monoid), must employ the distributive law, since that is the only law that connects the additive and multiplicative structures that combine to form the ring structure. Without the distributive law a ring degenerates to a set with two completely unrelated additive and multiplicative structures. So, in a sense, the distributive law is a *keystone* of the ring structure.

Comment: ❤️ last paragraph

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). just kidding

Comment: @Clyde This was posted nine years ago when the site was still in poulation mode and site politics was very different (when many of us believed that SE might provide us with better tools for dealing with site oprganization  - but they never did). Most all prolific users will have dupes in the old days.

Answer (score 7):

$$1 + (-1) = 0$$
$$-1(1 + (-1)) = -1(0)$$
$$-1(1) + -1(-1) = 0$$
$$-1 + -1(-1) = 0$$
$$1 + (-1) + -1(-1) = 0 + 1$$
$$0 + -1(-1) = 1$$
$$-1(-1) = 1$$

Comment: Note that the proof implicitly assumes that the *distributive law* holds for *all* integers, not just positive integers.

Answer (score 3):

If you assume some basic properties of addition and multiplication:

$$(-1) \times 0 = 0$$ $$(-1) \times ((-1) + 1) = 0$$ $$(-1) \times (-1) + (-1) \times 1 = 0$$ $$(-1) \times (-1) + (-1) = 0$$ $$(-1) \times (-1) + (-1) +1 = 0+1$$ $$(-1) \times (-1) + 0 = 1$$ $$(-1) \times (-1) = 1$$

Comment: Note that the proof implicitly assumes that the *distributive law* holds for *all* integers, not just positive integers.