# Explaining to a kid why a negative × negative = positive?

Tags: arithmetic, education

My son's just turning 8 this year and has just started to learn some of the basics of multiplications, including multiplication signs.

However, he's started asking me why a negative multiplied by another negative would make a positive. It's quite hard to explain to a kid and I'm not quite sure how to put it. I've seen the [other question regarding the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9933/why-is-negative-times-negative-positive) but I fear the concepts within those answers are much too difficult for my son to wrap his head around.

What's the best way to explain to my kid why a negative × negative = positive?  For reference, I'm looking for simple concepts to explain to a child to understand this.  At this point he could care less about dot products, absolute values, multiplicative identities.  He's just getting started with multiplication for crying out loud.

Comment: Related, almost dup: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9933/why-is-negative-times-negative-positive  The first two answers fit the bill.

Comment: @GEdgar I've tried explaining why it isn't a duplicate.  The answers there simply don't fit the bill.  Unless maybe I should start explaining exponentional equations to an 8 year old, and get started on the ti-89 for him as well.

Comment: @venidividicivicini I agree it isn't a duplicate of either question, and were someone to start at this question with all its great answers with the intention of explaining to a kid and follow the duplicates, they'd arguably get less relevant results. What can you do though.