# Real analysis using field axioms to prove

Tags: proof-verification, axioms

Prove that $(-x)(-y)=xy$ using field axiom theorems

My attempt

I know that $-(xy)$ is the additional inverse for $xy$, and I know $xy + -(xy) = 0$ (equation $1$)

I assumed that $(-x)(-y)=xy$ and substitute into eqn $1$ and I get

$(-x)(-y)+ -(xy) =0 $

so now I just have to show that this equation is still true to justify my claim that $xy=(-x)(-y)$

But how do I move on from here??

list of axioms : https://kevinbinz.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/group-theory-group-marriage-1.png

Comment: You can't prove (-x)(-y) = xy by assuming (-x)(-y) = xy. Could you list/link to the axioms you are allowed to use?

Comment: https://kevinbinz.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/group-theory-group-marriage-1.png

Comment: See also: [Simple proof using only field axioms: $(-x)(-y) = xy$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1719772)
[How to show that $(-a)(-b)=ab$ holds in a field?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1904420)

Answer (score -1):

by associativity and commutativity of multiplication
we get

$(-x)(-y) = (-1.x)(-1.y) = (-1.-1)(x.y)$

now remains to prove $-1.-1 = 1$

consider $-1 + -1.-1  = -1.1 + -1.-1 = -1(-1 + 1) = 0 $

Comment: can i say that -x is equal to (-1)(x)? , i don't think you can do that since it's not in the axioms, probably requires a proof?

Comment: yes you can prove it, since x + -1.x = x.1 + -1.x = x(1+ -1) = 0