# How to show that $(-a)(-b)=ab$ holds in a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a field. How do I prove that $$\forall a,b \in \mathcal{F}:(-a)(-b)=ab.$$

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: See also: [Simple proof using only field axioms:$(-x)(-y) = xy$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1719772)

Answer (score 5):

$$(a+(-a))b=0$$
$$ab+(-a)b=0$$
$$(-a)b=-(ab)$$

Now

$$(-a)(b+(-b))=0$$
$$(-a)b+(-a)(-b)=0$$
$$-(ab)+(-a)(-b)=0$$
$$(-a)(-b)=ab$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Proof that
$$(-a)(-b)+(-(ab))=0$$