# Showing that multiplying by $-1$ commutes with a unit and its inverse in an arbitrary ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

In an arbitrary ring, I have that $ab = 1$. I'm pretty certain that $a(-b) = -1$, but I'm not sure how to prove that the $-$ sign commutes. Is this necessarily true? Could someone point me in the direction of a proof or counterexample?

Comment: It's a general fact that $a(-b)=(-a)b=-(ab)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: You want to prove $a(-b)=-(ab)$.  That is, you want to prove $a(-b)$ is the additive inverse of $ab$.  So try adding $a(-b)$ and $ab$ and see if you can show the sum is $0$.

Comment: $ab + a(-b) = a(b-b) = 0$. Got it! Thank you.

Comment: @Alex   $\,a(-b)\,$ and $\,(-a)b\,$ are both inverses of $\,ab\,$ so are equal by **uniqueness of inverses.** which yields a proof of the [Law of Signs.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/9940/242)