# Proof of $(-a)b=(-b)a$ starting from axioms

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, axioms

Prove from axioms that 
$ 
\forall_{a,b\in\mathbb{R}}:(-a)b=(-b)a$ , but $a0=0$ is allowed.

My attempt:
$LHS=(-a)b=(-a)b+0=(-a)b+(ba+(-ba))=((-a)b+ba)+(-ba)=b(-a+a)+(-ba)=b0+(-ba)=0+(-ba)=-ba$

So, now I need show that $-ba=(-b)a$

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/9940/242) for a *conceptual* way using uniqueness of inverses.

Comment: This is it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, by the looks of it. You just need to prove that $ba + (-b)a = 0$, so that $(-b)a = -(ba)$ by uniqueness of additive inverses. But you can do this using distributivity, commutativity and the rule $a0=0$:
$$ba+(-b)a = (b-b)a = 0a = a0 = 0$$
[If you haven't proved uniqueness of additive inverses, then you should do that first.]