# Basic mathmatical concepts( multiplication)

Tags: arithmetic

Here is a conundrum I pondered upon while solving an equation - 
2x2 , generally means we are adding 2 two times , that is , 2+2 
Then , 
(-2)x(-2) , should go like this (-2)+(-2)=-4 , 
But , that's not true , the answer is +4 . 
Can anybody figure out and help me with it..

Comment: just consider $-(2 \cdot 2)$ as the opposite of $2 \cdot 2$

Comment: $(-2) \times (-2)= 2 \times [(-1) \times (-2)]$ i.e. you are multiplying for $2$ (i.e. adding with itself) the result of "swapping the sign", i.e. mult for $(-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

We need to refer to [**axioms**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FieldAxioms.html) and since $+1$ is the [**neutral element**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) for product, the idea is that we have

- $(-2) \cdot (+1)=-2$

and then

- $(-2) \cdot (-1)=+2 \implies (-2) \cdot (-2)=+4$

For a detailed discussion refer to  the related

- **[Why is negative times negative = positive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9933/505767)**